How to efficiently pass data between Threads in JMeter for high number of users
I've been assigned the task of testing a site with following criteria:

Log into each tenant with 2 users
user 1 should create a sale order
user 2 should update the sale order
user 1 should confirm the sale order
user 2 should generate the report

The main issue I'm facing here is differentiating and delegating the task to users!
I've tried employing a CSV file for recording the login details, along with tenant names, but every thread read the file same way and assigned the details for user 1, essentially making every user as user 1.
The current make shift way I'm using is setting the CSRF-Token and JSessionID of user to a property with format tenantNumber_userNumber_csrfToken and tenantNumber_userNumber_jSessionId.
and then using a JSR223 script to create
def lastTenantId = vars.get("lastTenantId")
def jSessionId = vars.get("jSessionId")
def csrfToken = vars.get("csrfToken")

def baseTenantVar = "${lastTenantId}_user"


if (props.getProperty(baseTenantVar + "1_jSessionId") == null) {
    props.put(baseTenantVar + "1_jSessionId", jSessionId)
     props.put(baseTenantVar + "1_csrfToken", csrfToken)
     log.info("Assigned User 1 for tenant ${lastTenantId}")
} else {
    props.put(baseTenantVar + "2_jSessionId", jSessionId)
     props.put(baseTenantVar + "2_csrfToken", csrfToken)
     log.info("Assigned User 2 for tenant ${lastTenantId}")
}

and destroy
def tenantNumber = vars.get("tenantNumber")

props.remove("test${tenantNumber}_user1_jSessionId")
props.remove("test${tenantNumber}_user1_csrfToken")
log.info("removed User 1 for tenant ${tenantNumber}")

props.remove("test${tenantNumber}_user2_jSessionId")
props.remove("test${tenantNumber}_user2_csrfToken")
log.info("removed User 2 for tenant ${tenantNumber}")

props.remove("test${tenantNumber}_SO_id")
log.info("removed the sale order id for tenant ${tenantNumber}")

these properties every time the thread group is run.
After login, any operation I want to perform, for say user 1, is encapsulated with an If controller, to check if the current CSRF-Token and JSessionID matches with the User 1 of the tenant.
This is getting my job done at small scale, which is less than 50 user just for creating and testing if the sent data and performed action are working as intended, but the real testing I've to do with 1000, 2000 and 5000 concurrent users, for which I'm sure this is not a very memory efficient idea.
What other ways I can try to get the same output ?

Groovy scripts are compiled and cached so it should be fine from memory perspective.
Another approach I can think of is using Inter-Thread Communication Plugin which provides a FIFO queue which can be shared across threads and written/read concurrently
You can install Inter-Thread Communication Plugin using JMeter Plugins Manager
